# How do I get access to keys/attributes of a simple-xml object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a xml-object looks like this:

```
<search typ="car" sub="all" out="test" epc="2" tsc="1" rcc="111" tpc="111" cur="DOL" itc="10">
```

Or with var_dump():

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1012]
  public 'search' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[1078]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=9)
              'typ' => string 'car' (length=8)
              'sub' => string 'all' (length=3)
              'out' => string 'test' (length=11)
              'epc' => string '2' (length=1)
              'tsc' => string '1' (length=1)
              'rcc' => string '111' (length=3)
              'tpc' => string '111' (length=3)
              'cur' => string 'DOL' (length=3)
              'itc' => string '10' (length=2)
```

How do I get access to the attributes of the xml knot?

Comment: just to clarify, is this a self closing tag `<search />` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `->attributes` to access the node's attributes. Example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string); // or load_file

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml->attributes());
```

Individually:

```
// PHP 5.4 or greater (dereference)
echo $xml->attributes()['typ'];
```

Comment: Do you know something about the JMS Serializer? How can I get the attributes with the JMS?

Comment: Actually, most of the time, you don't need the `->attributes()` method at all. Nor do you need the array dereference if you are using it, because `->attributes()->typ` will then work. See my answer for a few examples of when you want this.

Answer (score 1):

As shown on [the basic usage examples in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), the standard way to access an attribute is using array access (`$element['attributeName']`), e.g.

```
echo $search['typ'];
$typ = (string)$search['typ'];
```

Note that the attribute is returned as an object, so you usually want to "cast" to string (or int, etc) when storing it in a variable.

To iterate over all attributes, you can use [the `->attributes()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php), e.g.

```
foreach ( $search->attributes() as $name => $value ) {
     echo "$name: $value\n";
     $some_hash[ $name ] = (string)$value;
}
```

The `attributes()` method is also needed if you have XML namespaces, e.g. `

```
$sx = simplexml_load_string(
    '<foo xlmns:bar="http://example.com#SOME_XMLNS" bar:becue="yum" />'
);
echo $sx->attributes('http://example.com#SOME_XMLNS')->becue;
// Or, shorter but will break if the XML is generated with different prefixes
echo $sx->attributes('bar', true)->becue;
```